# Installing R packages and execution errors

Tags: r, rstudio

[a screenshot for Rstudio UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhmh8.jpg)

While coding or installing any package,  the dialog box keeps on popping up. What could be the possible error?

Comment: Please read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and adjust your question accordingly so the community can answer it.

Comment: Try http://community.rstudio.com/ - this looks like it could be an RSTudio system or configuration problem and needs specialist help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such an error do the following: - Save all your scripts
                                    - Quit session (cltr + Q)
                                    -Restart your Rstudio and try installing any 
                                     package

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an error with you directory. It can not access it